# Facebook c# sdk login and post access token to server

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the javascript sdk to login and post the accesstoken to the server as outlined in the facebook c# sdk getting started page. I am having a few problems.

1. it uses auth.authResponseChange which fires everytime which causes a redirect loop
2. if i change it to auth.login, it will only be called when a user logs in via my site. it doesn't work if they are already logged into fb.
3. How do i post the accesstoken only once back to the server and store it in the session?
4. if i use oauth authentication on the server, is it possible to pass the access token back to the javascript sdk?

   ```
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
       if (response.status === 'connected') {
           // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
           // app, and response.authResponse supplies
           // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
           // request, and the time the access token 
           // and signed request each expire
           var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
           var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

           // TODO: Handle the access token
           // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
           // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
           var form = document.createElement("form");
           form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
           form.setAttribute("action", '/FacebookLogin.ashx');

           var field = document.createElement("input");
           field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
           field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
           field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
           form.appendChild(field);

           document.body.appendChild(form);
           form.submit();

       } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
           // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
           // but has not authenticated your app
       } else {
          // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Try one of the other auth-related events: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: but i still need to check loginstatus on every page load?

Comment: What are you having to pass the access token back to the JavaScript SDK for?

Comment: I am thinking that its more efficient to do queries and stuff from the client browser. For example, i may do fql queries to select like counts and use fb friend selectors.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I also have the same problem of redirect loop and haven't been able to figure this out!!! any pointers will be helpful.